# Addresses in structures

Tags: c, struct, printf, string-literals, pointer-to-pointer

The following is an abstract version of a problem I am currently having.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        char * bar
    } struct_t;
    
    struct_t foo = {};
    foo.bar = "test";
    struct_t * p_foo = &foo;
    
    char * p = p_foo->bar;
    char ** a = &p_foo;
    char ** b = &p_foo->bar;
    
    printf("%s %s",*a,*b);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the code to print `test` twice, which it doesn't. Why is that happening?

******************************* EDIT *******************************

The abstraction I WANTED to post is the following, it's basically what you guys pointed out to be wrong in my first attempt - thanks for that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        char * bar;
    } struct_t;
    
    struct_t foo = { .bar = "test" };
    
    // works
    struct_t * p_foo = &foo;
    char * p_bar = &p_foo->bar[0];
    char ** a = &p_bar;
    
    // does not work
    char ** b = &p_foo->bar;
    
    printf("%s %s",*a,*b);

    return 0;
}
```

However, this version does actually print `test` twice, meaning that the abstraction does not reproduce my problem, so I have to try once again:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void callback(void ** ppContext)
{
    char * pString = (char *) *(ppContext);
    printf("%s",pString);
}

int main()
{
    typedef struct {
        char buffer[5];
    } struct_t;
    
    struct_t ctrl = { .buffer = "test" };
    struct_t * pCtrl = &ctrl;
    
    // works
    char * pString = &pCtrl->buffer[0];
    callback((void **) &pString);
    
    // does not work
    callback((void **) &pCtrl->buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the actual code, I just deleted everything non-related. The section named `//works` prints `test` as expected. The section named `//does not work` does not.
(I commented out one of them respectively to test it, an fflush inbetween them would make testing them simultaneously possible.)

I expect `&pCtrl->buffer[0]` to be the address of the first char in the buffer which is stored in pString. Since the callback is called with the address of pString, the `(char *) *(ppContext)` in the callback makes it the actuall string again, i.e., a pointer to the first char in the buffer.

However, I would expect `&pCtrl->buffer` to be the address of the string as well, if `pCtrl->buffer` is the string itself, i.e., the address of the first char in the buffer. But apparantly that is not the case and I don't understand why.

Comment: How is casting `struct_t*` into `char*` reasonable here? You likely need to enable more warnings.

Comment: `clang` helpfully points out this: `warning: incompatible pointer types initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'struct_t **' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]`

Comment: Expecting anything from code that doesn't compile cleanly is not recommended.

Comment: It's perhaps more interesting to inspect `printf("%p\n%p\n", &p_foo, &p_foo->bar);`

Comment: Why do you expect it to print `test` twice?

Comment: I edited the initial question.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is that happening?

`a = &p_foo` is a pointer to `p_foo`. `p_foo` is a pointer and points to `foo`. By doing `*a` you are trying to print *the value* of the pointer `p_foo`, i.e. the *address* of `foo` itself, as a string.

If you *really* want to do that, you might dereference `a` to get `p_foo` and then dereference `p_foo` to get the address of `foo` which is equal to the address of `foo.bar` which holds the address of the string to be printed:

```
char ***a = &p_foo;
printf("%s", **a);
```

But really, your code breaks language constraints and is invalid. You should use correct types and properly access structure members:

```
struct_t **a = &p_foo;    
printf("%s", (*a)->bar);
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters at least there is a typo in the structure declaration

```
typedef struct {
    char * bar
    ^^^^^^^^^^
} struct_t;
```

you need to place a semicolon after the data member declaration

```
typedef struct {
    char * bar;
} struct_t;
```

The initialization in this declaration

```
struct_t foo = {};
```

is invalid before the C23 Standard. You may not use empty braces if your compiler does not compile the program according to the C23 Standard.  You could write for example

```
struct_t foo = { NULL };
```

or

```
struct_t foo = { .bar = NULL };
```

or simply

```
struct_t foo = { .bar = "test" };
```

For this declaration

```
char ** a = &p_foo;
```

the compiler should issue a message because there is no implicit conversion between the pointer types `char **` and `struct_t **`.

As for your question then dereferencing the pointer `a` in the call of `printf`

```
printf("%s %s",*a,*b);
```

you get the pointer `p_foo` that points to the object  of the type
`struct_t *` declared like.

```
struct_t * p_foo = &foo;
```

The pointer does not contain the address of the first character of the string literal `"test"`. Instead it contains the address of the object  `foo`.

On the other hand the pointer `p`

```
char * p = p_foo->bar;
```

was assigned by the value of the pointer `p_foo->bar` that contains the address of the string literal. So using the expression `*b` in the call of `printf` yields the expected result opposite to using the the pointer expression `*a`.

Just compare how the pointers that is with which values they were initialized

```
foo.bar = "test";
struct_t * p_foo = &foo;

char * p = p_foo->bar;
```

In fact the last declaration

```
char * p = p_foo->bar;
```

looks like

```
char * p = "test";
```

of course provided that matching string literals are stored by the compiler as one string literal.

You can check the values of addresses produced by the pointer expressions `*a` and `*b` the following way

```
 printf("%p %p\n", ( void * )*a,( void * )*b);
```

To get the expected result you need to write

```
char **a = ( char ** )p_foo;
```

instead of

```
char ** a = &p_foo;
```

That is now the pointer `a` points to the object `foo` of the structure. Dereferencing the pointer you get the data member (pointer) `bar` address of which coincides with the address of the object `foo` that contains the data member `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs with the b variable declaration: char ** b = &p_foo->bar;. Here, you are assigning the address of p_foo->bar, which is a char*, to a char** variable (b).

The correct type for b should be char*, not char**. This is because p_foo->bar is already of type char*. Assigning its address to a char** will lead to an incorrect level of indirection.

Please refer to the below code:

```
typedef struct {
    char * bar;
} struct_t;

struct_t foo = {};
foo.bar = "test";
struct_t * p_foo = &foo;

char * p = p_foo->bar;
char ** a = &p_foo;
char * b = p_foo->bar;

printf("%s %s", *a, b);
```